# Fellini-esque movie with a general in a toilet

Tags: identify-this-movie

It was likely an Italian film made in the 70s.  The scene was a military parade.  The parading army and audiences were waiting for the general who was on the toilet.  He finally stood up off the seat, turned around and accidentally dropped one of his medals into the toilet bowl.  He then tried to fish the medal out again but this only resulted in him dropping more medals into the toilet.  Finally he had had enough, drew his pistol and shot himself!

Can anyone identify the movie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The film is "Signore e Signori Buonanotte" / "[Goodnight, Ladies and Gentlemen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodnight,_Ladies_and_Gentlemen)", 1976. The general was played by Ugo Tognazzi.